# Boost::Mutex in class not thread-safe

Tags: c++, oop, boost-mutex

I'm learning concurrent programming and what I want to do is have a class where each object it responsible for running its own Boost:Thread. I'm a little over my head with this code because it uses A LOT of functionality that I'm not that comfortable with (dynamically allocated memory, function pointers, concurrency etc etc). It's like every line of code I had to check some references to get it right.

(Yes, all allocated memory is accounted for in the real code!)

I'm having trouble with the mutexes. I declare it static and it seems to get the same value for all the instances (as it should). The code is STILL not thread safe.

The mutex should stop the the threads (right?) from progressing any further in case someone else locked it. Because mutexes are scoped (kind of a neat functionality) and it's within the if statement that should look the other threads out no? Still I get console out puts that clearly suggests it is not thread safe.

Also I'm not sure I'm using the static vaiable right. I tried different ways of refering to it (Seller::ticketSaleMutex) but the only thing that worked was "this->ticketSaleMutex" which seems very shady and it seems to defeat the purpose of it being static.

Seller.h:

```
class Seller
{
public:     
    //Some vaiables
private:
    //Other variables
    static boost::mutex ticketSaleMutex;      //Mutex definition
};
```

Seller.cpp:

```
boost::mutex Seller::ticketSaleMutex;         //Mutex declaration

void Seller::StartTicketSale()
{
    ticketSale = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&Seller::SellTickets, this));

}
void Seller::SellTickets()
{
    while (*totalSoldTickets < totalNumTickets)
    {
        if ([Some time tick])
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock(this->ticketSaleMutex);
            (*totalSoldTickets)++;
            std::cout << "Seller " << ID << " sold ticket " << *totalSoldTickets << std::endl;
        }

    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    std::vector<Seller*> seller;
    const int numSellers = 10;
    int numTickets = 40;
    int *soldTickets = new int;
    *soldTickets = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numSellers; i++)
    {
        seller.push_back(new Seller(i, numTickets, soldTickets));
        seller[i]->StartTicketSale();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Seller::ticketSaleMutex` should definitely work. It is totally equivalent to `this->ticketSaleMutex`.

Comment: "error C2655: 'Seller::ticketSaleMutex' : definition or redeclaration illegal in current scope" + "error C2371: 'ticketSaleMutex' : redefinition; different basic types"

Comment: That's obv because I'm doing it wrong, it works when I use mutexes correctly (as in the answer)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will create a temporary that is immediately destroyed:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock(this->ticketSaleMutex);
```

resulting in no synchronization. You need to declare a variable:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock local_lock(this->ticketSaleMutex);
```

Comment: Leaving you with all the overhead of locking the mutex, with none of the synchronization benefit.  Ouch.

Comment: Oh it was that simple :D Just goes to show I need to practice one thing at a time or it'll just be confusing. That single line of code contained 3 things I never used before: the this pointer, function pointers (well obv cause I use the this pointer) and concurrency.

Comment: As `ticketSaleMutex` is `static` you also use `Seller::ticketSaleMutex`. Which, IMO, is more clear as `this->` makes it look like an instance variable (non-static).

Comment: Yeah, but I get a compiler error when I do that: "error C2371: 'ticketSaleMutex' : redefinition; different basic types "

Comment: That's obv because I'm doing it wrong, it works when I use mutexes correctly (as in the answer)

Comment: That is a correct way to refer to a `static` class member. See http://ideone.com/8h6iu for example.

Comment: Within the context of a member method, static variables do not need their scope resolved by either dereferencing 'this' or by decorating them with a scope resolution operator.  Within any member method of class Seller, you may simply refer directly to the static variable by name: `boost::mutex::scoped_lock foo(ticketSaleMutex);`